# SSIS SCD Transform Start Date and End date are the same - how can this be?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, scd, scd2

I have an issue with my ETL.
I have a dimension table that has some SCD 1 and SCD 2 columns - I have mapped these correctly in the SCD Transformation as `Changing Attribute` and `Historical Attribute` respectively.

Then on the Historical Attribute Options page I have checked the `Use start and end dates to identify current and expired records`, inputting my ValidFrom column as the `Start date column` and my ValidTo column as the `End date column`.

As I understand it, this should mean that any inserted records are given a ValidFrom of the current datetime value and their ValidTo column remains `NULL`. And for those who already exist but are the outdated record, their ValidTo becomes the current datetime value.

However, on some but not all records that get imported - the latest record inserted is inserted with the exact same datetime in the ValidFrom and ValidTo record.
Which becomes an enormous pain as I am left to view that record as invalid in my queries, and the knockon effect on fact table loading.

Can anyone help as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check your source set of data? It might contain more than 2 rows per business entity during the specific load process. If you don't have any other timestamps in your source that you could use to identify real date&time change - that might happens having at least 3 changes for one row in the same pass.
BTW Do you know SCD Merge Wizard app?
https://github.com/SQLPlayer/SCD-Merge-Wizard

Comment: Have you had any luck solving this? I have this same situation and I haven't had any luck finding or solving the issue...